# MySQL find the mode of multiple subsets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database like this:

```
custNum         date        purchase        dayOfWeek
  333         2001-01-01    23.23            1
  333         2001-03-04    34.56            5
  345         2008-02-02    22.55            3
  345         2008-04-05    12.35            6
  ...          ...           ...            ...
```

I'm trying to get the mode (most frequently occuring value) for the dayOfWeek column for each customer.  Basically it would be the day of the week each customer shops the most on. Like:

```
custNum         max(count(dayofweek(date)))
 333                   5
 345                   3
 356                   2
 388                   7
 ...                  ...
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: How do you identify a purchase - what is your primary key? Is there a `purchaseId` field you have not shown us?

Comment: Then what is you PK? Is it {custNum, date}? If so, how do you distinguish between two purchases by same user that happen on the same day? Do you just sum them together into the same row?

Comment: there's no pk.  each customer has one row per day that sums all purchases.

Comment: When you say, "each customer has one row per day", do you actually mean "each customer has one row per **date**"? If yes, this is your PK right there: {custNum, date}. You better define it in the database or else you may end-up with two rows for the same customer for the same date, contradicting your own rules. Generally, not having a PK is a **very** bad practice. If you also happen to use InnoDB, you'll be depriving yourself of a good optimization opportunity through clustering.

Comment: Now to the next question: why are you attempting to count days of week that have at least one purchase in them? Shouldn't you be summing the amount of money in `purchase` instead? This is more in alignment what most people would call "customer shops the most".

Answer (score 3):

```
select custNum, dayOfWeek
from tableName t
group by custNum, dayOfWeek
having dayOfWeek = (
    select dayOfWeek
    from tableName
    where custNum = t.custNum
    group by dayOfWeek
    order by count(*) desc, dayOfWeek
    limit 1
)
```